# SharePoint Add-in (App) still works after modifying the client id and secret in provider hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I've been working on a Sharepoint Add-in that is provider-hosted.  I registered the add-in via **AppRegNew.apsx**.  Then I updated the **AppManifest.xml** in the add-in project and the **web.config** in the provider-hosted web project with the client id and client secret.  I deployed everything and it all works fine.

I then went to **AppRegNew.aspx** again and registered a new app.  This time I took the client id and client secret and updated just the web.config in the aforementioned provider-hosted web project and deployed it.

My Sharepoint Add-in still works even though the client id in the add-in app does not match the client id in the web.config of the provider-hosted web.  Shouldn't this cause things to break?

Comment: Did you trust the second App as well on site (using the second set of client Id and client secret?). If yes, then remove the second app from your site and try again. Also, please explain what you are doing in the add-in that 'still works'.